# Comparing two objects with nested lists in Java

Tags: java, java-stream, nested-lists

We have two externally maintained NoSQL databases, a legacy one and a new one. The records on these databases need to be compared for equality, and the new one must be updated to match the legacy one. The decision to carry this out using a Java application was not mine, but one which I must now implement.

Essentially the objects are returned and have various nested lists. I need to perform the java equivalent of joins on these lists, finding out at each nested list if the object is present in only legacy system (left outer join where right join key is null), only the new system (right outer join where left join key is null), or present in both (inner join). If they are present in both, I then need to then carry out the same logic on the nested list.

Example below:

```
// Objects below

    class Qualification {
        String qualificationName;
        String qualificationValue;
    }

    class Person {
        String personId;
        List<Qualification> qualifications;
    }

    class Group {
        String groupId;
        List<Person> people;
    }
    
    class DatabaseResponse {
        String recordId;
        List<Group> groups;
    }
```

So I have two lists of DatabaseResponses. I want to check records where the recordId matches from each database.

- Records found only in the old system need added to the new one
- Records found only in the new system need removed from it
- Records which match need compared further.

We then compare the Groups in the same system, joining on groupId.

- Records found only in the old system need added to the new one
- Records found only in the new system need removed from it
- Records which match need compared further.

Next we need to compare the People in the matching Groups, joining on personId.

- Records found only in the old system need added to the new one
- Records found only in the new system need removed from it
- Records which match need compared further.

Finally we need to compare each qualification, checking the name and value are correct. Based on this, we will need to add/update/delete the new system based on the old one. There are records which are to be ignored, so some of the joins will have flags which need to be ignored.

I have tried doing this with lists, using the .equals method setting the join key in there. But I feel maybe streams will be the right way to do this, possibly with a flatMap, as I will need to reference parent objects when updating in the NoSQLdatabase? Any help is appreciated.

```
for(DatabaseResponse legacyResponse : legacyList){
    for(DatabaseResponse newResponse : newList){
        if(legacyResponse.equals(newResponse){
          // cycle through each responses groups to find the ones that match

          // cycle through each matching group to compare their people etc...
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure that you can handle both databases in memory at the same time? How big are them?

Comment: They are being sent record by record via an API, Its not an ideal solution but this is basically the only way this can be done - through API's, which is why this Java application is required

Comment: I wonder if understand this problem correctly? As a result of **each** the step you've described you need the following: a list of *groups to insert* and a list of *groups to remove* from DB; a list of *people to insert* and a list of *people to remove* from DB; a list of *people to update*.

Comment: Can you provide your imperative solution so that it'll be more how to translate it into streams?

Comment: shown something there..

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your goal correctly you as a result need the following:

- a collection of `Group` objects that have to be inserted into the new DB and a collection of `Group` objects that have to be removed from the new DB;
- the same for the `Person` objects;
- the same for the `Qualification` objects;

My approach is to generate two maps `Map<Group, Set<Person>>` for old and new DB. And then use them to get **unions** and **differences** (in terms of the *set theory*) for *groups*, *people* and *qualifications*.

I assume that the *equality* of `Group` and `Person` objects is based solely on their **id**.

**Note**: *multi-line functions* (especially those that you see in `getQualifByPersToRemove()` and `getQualifByPersToAdd()`) has to be avoided  and normally extracted into a *separate method*.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<DatabaseResponse> oldResp = getResp() // fetching responces
        List<DatabaseResponse> newResp = getResp() // fetching responces

        Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld = getPersByGroupId(oldResp);
        Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew = getPersByGroupId(newResp);

        List<Group> groupsToRemove = getGroupsToRemove(persByGroupIdOld, persByGroupIdNew);
        List<Group> groupsToAdd = getGroupsToAdd(persByGroupIdOld, persByGroupIdNew);

        Set<Person> persToRemove = getPersToRemove(persByGroupIdOld, persByGroupIdNew);
        Set<Person> persToAdd = getPersToAdd(persByGroupIdOld, persByGroupIdNew);

        Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> qualifByPersToRemove = getQualifByPersToRemove(persByGroupIdOld, persByGroupIdNew);
        Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> qualifByPersToAdd = getQualifByPersToAdd(persByGroupIdOld, persByGroupIdNew);
    }
```

```
    public static Map<Group, Set<Person>> getPersByGroupId(List<DatabaseResponse> responses) {
        return responses.stream()
                .flatMap(resp -> resp.getGroups().stream())
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                                               Collectors.flatMapping(group -> group.getPeople().stream(),
                                                                  Collectors.toSet())));
    }
```

```
    public static List<Group> getGroupsToRemove(Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld,
                                                Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew) {

        return persByGroupIdNew.keySet().stream()
                .filter(group -> !persByGroupIdOld.containsKey(group))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
    public static List<Group> getGroupsToAdd(Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld,
                                             Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew) {

        return persByGroupIdOld.keySet().stream()
                .filter(group -> !persByGroupIdNew.containsKey(group))
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }
```

```
    public static Set<Person> getPersToRemove(Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld,
                                              Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew) {

        return persByGroupIdNew.keySet().stream()
                .filter(persByGroupIdOld::containsKey) // exist in both DB
                .flatMap(group -> {
                    List<Person> persDiff = new ArrayList<>(persByGroupIdNew.get(group));
                    persDiff.removeAll(persByGroupIdOld.get(group));
                    return persDiff.stream();
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // set is used because person could potentially belong to many groups
    }
```

```
    public static Set<Person> getPersToAdd(Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld,
                                           Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew) {

        return persByGroupIdOld.keySet().stream()
                .filter(persByGroupIdOld::containsKey) // exist in both DB
                .flatMap(group -> {
                    List<Person> persDiff = new ArrayList<>(persByGroupIdOld.get(group));
                    persDiff.removeAll(persByGroupIdNew.get(group));
                    return persDiff.stream(); // assumption that equality of the Person class is based on the personId only
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toSet()); // set is used because person could potentially belong to many groups
    }
```

```
    public static Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> getQualifByPersToRemove(Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld,
                                                                          Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew) {

        return persByGroupIdOld.keySet().stream()
                .filter(persByGroupIdNew::containsKey) // exist in both DB
                .flatMap(group -> {
                    Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> qualifByCommonPersOld = getQualifByPers(persByGroupIdOld.get(group));
                    Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> qualifByCommonPersNew = getQualifByPers(persByGroupIdNew.get(group));
                    return qualifByCommonPersNew.entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(entry -> qualifByCommonPersOld.containsKey(entry.getKey())) // intersection of people
                            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue()
                                    .equals(qualifByCommonPersOld.get(entry.getKey()))) // qualifications sets for a particular person don't match
                            .map(entry -> { // qualification that aren't present in the old DB
                                Set<Qualification> newQualif = new HashSet<>(entry.getValue());
                                newQualif.removeAll(qualifByCommonPersOld.get(entry.getKey()));
                                return Map.entry(entry.getKey(), newQualif); // Person object and qualifications are present only in new DB
                            });
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
```

```
    public static Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> getQualifByPersToAdd(Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdOld,
                                                                       Map<Group, Set<Person>> persByGroupIdNew) {

        return persByGroupIdOld.keySet().stream()
                .filter(persByGroupIdNew::containsKey) // exist in both DB
                .flatMap(group -> {
                    Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> qualifByCommonPersOld = getQualifByPers(persByGroupIdOld.get(group));
                    Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> qualifByCommonPersNew = getQualifByPers(persByGroupIdNew.get(group));
                    return qualifByCommonPersOld.entrySet().stream()
                            .filter(entry -> qualifByCommonPersNew.containsKey(entry.getKey())) // intersection of people
                            .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue()
                                    .equals(qualifByCommonPersNew.get(entry.getKey()))) // qualifications sets for a particular person don't match
                            .map(entry -> {
                                Set<Qualification> oldQualif = new HashSet<>(entry.getValue());
                                oldQualif.removeAll(qualifByCommonPersNew.get(entry.getKey()));
                                return Map.entry(entry.getKey(), oldQualif); // Person object and qualifications are not present or differ
                            });
                })
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(Map.Entry::getKey, Map.Entry::getValue));
    }
```

```
    public static Map<Person, Set<Qualification>> getQualifByPers(Set<Person> people) {
        return people.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(),
                        Collectors.flatMapping(pers -> pers.getQualifications().stream(), Collectors.toSet())));
    }
```